# How to add a value to an existing hash without a key

Tags: ruby, hash

I need to assign the numbers 0-100000 to a hash without giving a key.

Ruby uses Murmur as hash function. How can I add a value without having a key, like in C, letting it handle collision and other things. Is it possible? Can I give just the value to hash and let it evaluate the key, then insert to itself?

In a normal hashing operation, we have a hash function, and a table. We use value as the argument of the hash function, then we get a key in return. The value is inserted to the key location in the table (if a collision happens, double hashing or something else used).

Is it possible to do the same type of hashing in Ruby? Or am I stuck with default ways? Can I just throw the value into a function, then it evaluates the key, and inserts the value to the hash table or not?

Comment: So, why not an array? If you are not interested in keys.

Comment: I am trying to make a comparison between uthash of C, and hashes of Ruby. I need to create a hash with elements 0-100K and, search it for elements between 0-200K. Then I will compare memory and time usage, but it has to be a hash.

Comment: "Can I give just the value to hash and let it evaluate the key" - what key? You didn't provide one. If you're looking to test collision handling and whatnot, maybe use the same key for all values?

Comment: uthash requires a key too. So I'm completely lost as to what you're trying to do here. Perhaps, it's the other way around: you're not interested in __values__?

Comment: Post your C code and then we might be able to help you writing equivalent Ruby code.

Comment: edited my question.

Comment: "We use value as the argument of the hash function, then we get a key in return" - this is not how hash maps work, unfortunately. The whole point of them is that you use the key to lookup the value. If you know the value already, you don't need the map. You apply hash function to the key and use the result to place the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common solution is to simply use the value as a key. Hence:

```
value = "xxx"
hash[value] = 1
```

This way, you clearly document that the actual values (all `1`) of this particular hash are of no use, and you will get de-duplicated values. `Hash` will do the usual hashing internally, you don't need to worry about it at all.

I use `1` as value here, but the actual value is completely irrelevant. I don't use `nil` as that is the default return value of `hash[nonexistant_value]`.

If your values are more complex, check out http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html for specifics about them.

Answer (score 1):

Just store into the hash using the calculated hash of the key, rather than the key itself:

```
hash[hash_func(key)] = value
```

That is, instead of mapping `key` -> `value` directly, this maps `hash_func(key)` -> value. The implementation may pass your hashed key value through another hash function internally, but you needn't care about that.

However, in comments it now comes to light that you want to apply the hash function to the *value*, not any other key. In that case, just use a [set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) and be done with it. Then, all you need to do is add values to the set:

```
s = Set.new
s.add(value)
```

There's no need to calculate the hash of anything; Set will take care of it for you.

In short, this seems to be a case of the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You needed to store a set of values in a data structure (and presumably be able to check if those values were stored in an efficient manner). Instead of asking about this, you asked about hash functions and tables. If you had asked about what you really needed, instead of asking about something else that you thought you could use to solve the original problem, you would have had a useful answer much more quickly.

Comment: Thanks! That was the thing that I meant. But then, I have to write my own hash function right? If I'm wrong, then how can I get the hashed value of key?

Comment: @wackyburkay if you "need to write your own hash function" then why not just use a plain, regular Ruby hash? I presumed that you already had a hash function. If you don't, your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: In a normal way, I would use this procedure: 1.give value to the hash function. 2.get key 3.instert value to the [key] position 4.if a collision happens, handle it. But in Ruby, i cant just do something like hash.add(x) because it requires the key too, for adding. You said "use regular ruby hash". Without having key, how can I? I will add integers 0-100K, but I cant "key" them with 1,2,3... I do not want my hash to be exactly like an array, there must be some buckets. How can I achieve this with regular Ruby hash? If I can't, have to write a hash function.

Comment: Use [`Object#hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-hash) as hash function, since it is the default in `Hash` implementation. That said, `hash[value.hash] = value` is your friend.

Comment: @mudasobwa: but this way the value will be stored at `value.hash.hash`. And it won't create any "buckets" anyway. 100k integers will have 100k distinct hashes.

Comment: @wackyburkay: if you want a lame ass hash function which will give collisions, use  `my_hash[value % 100] = value` or something.

Comment: Aha. I knew I had to write my own hash function. % (division method) is a hash function here, I suppose. But I wonder why it says "ruby uses murmur" in documentation? where does ruby use it if we give both the key and value?

Comment: @wackyburkay: it uses it on the key, of course. See my last comment to the question.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help. That solves the issue.

Comment: @wackyburkay what you are describing is a hash _set_ - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html. It deals with hashing so that you don't have to worry about it; you just store and retrieve values, and never need to know what the hash value is. Your steps (1), (2) and (4) are then redundant - they are handled by the Set.

Comment: @davmac: Yeah, it's really not clear what he wants. I think he wants to benchmark two hash map implementations and how they handle specific data set. But I'm not sure.